# post method not called in volley lib - android

Tags: php, android

I'm using volley lib, but I faced a strange problem . 
The volley lib doesn't returns any value. but I tested my web service on this site `https://www.hurl.it/` and it returns value.

**My webservice :**

http://shadyab.com/Mobile/vitrin/index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['get_job_service_category'])){
        require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
        $object = new DB_Functions();
        echo json_encode($object->getJobServiceCategory());

    }
```

**My volley functions :**

```
    private void getAllCategories(){

    RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();

    StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            TagsClass.URL_ADDRESS,
            createMyReqSuccessListener(),
            createMyReqErrorListener()) {

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("get_job_service_category","-");
            return params;
        };
    };
    queue.add(myReq);

}

    private Response.Listener<String> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            parseResultOfServer(response.toString());
        }
    };
}


private void parseResultOfServer(String str){

    Log.e("sss", "=>" + str);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"=>"+str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("err","="+error.getMessage());

        }
    };
}
```

Where is my wrong?

**MyVollet.java** class :

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;


/**
 * Helper class that is used to provide references to initialized RequestQueue(s) and ImageLoader(s)
 * 
 * @author Ognyan Bankov
 * 
 */
public class MyVolley {
    private static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static ImageLoader mImageLoader;


    private MyVolley() {
        // no instances
    }


    public static void init(Context context) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        int memClass = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .getMemoryClass();
        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache(cacheSize));
    }


    public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            return mRequestQueue;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("RequestQueue not initialized");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns instance of ImageLoader initialized with {@see FakeImageCache} which effectively means
     * that no memory caching is used. This is useful for images that you know that will be show
     * only once.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        if (mImageLoader != null) {
            return mImageLoader;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ImageLoader not initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Solved  !!!**

I added `www` to http://shadyab.com/Mobile/vitrin/index.php and solved it !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think you are using code from this [Library](https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples) and I have tested your URL with this library and its working totally fine. Please check your code there might be some mistake.

Comment: Please post your `MyVolley.java` .

Comment: posted the content of this class.

Comment: is your onResponse method getting called or not? Or are you just receiving blank string as response?

Comment: Have you cleaned your app / uninstalled it before retesting? It could be an old cache.

Comment: please be sure if you are calling `init()` method of `MyVolley.java` in your ApplicationClass or somewhere at the start of your application.

Comment: @Droidwala response value is "" ;

Comment: @vipul_asri it called aat start of application .

Comment: @Hithredin yes. I unistalled and install my app.

Comment: When i tried testing out url you have provided on hurl.it , the response is infact coming as null..can you check it again?..And what kind of response you are expecting? JSON?

Comment: it returns a json output : `[{"id":"1","title":"\u062e\u062f\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0641\u0646\u06cc \u0645\u0647\u0646\u062f\u0633\u06cc"},{"id":"2","title":"\u0622\u0645\u0648\u0632\u0634"}]`

Answer (score 0):

change your code from this  :

```
Request.Method.POST
```

to this :

```
Method.POST
```

in your *StringRequest*. `Method` is an Interface of `Request.java` only.

You will get the Response String as :

```
[{"id":"1","title":"\u062e\u062f\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0641\u0646\u06cc
\u0645\u0647\u0646\u062f\u0633\u06cc"},{"id":"2","title":"\u0622\u0645\u0648\u06‌​32\u0634"}]
```